# GraphAPI returns "Resource Not Found" trying to get calendars

Tags: azure, api, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I am able to access the users using [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bid%7D)

But when I am trying to get calendars or events I am getting an Error: `Resource could not be discovered`

I am using the following URL

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/events](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bid%7D/events)

and

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/calendar](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bid%7D/calendar)

I do `have all calendar read and write permissions` in the Active directory

Can someone help me with this??

I am expecting to `get all the events from the calendar`

Comment: getting` all the events from the calendar` requires to make sure that the user has calendar. Then you may follow [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) to try to get them. the url should like: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/calendar/events`

Answer (score 0):

The error `"Resource Not Found"` usually occurs if the user doesn't have required **active licenses** assigned.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I tried to retrieve the calendar of the user with no active licenses:

[image]

***I got the same error as below:***

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/calendar
```

[image]

I created an **Azure AD application and added API permissions** like below:

[image]

I generated the **access token** using the below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:clientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

I tried to retrieve the calendar events of the users having ***active O365 licenses*** like below:

[image]

I am able to successfully **retrieve the calendar events successfully** like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/calendar/events
```

[image]

***If still the issue persists***, check whether the user have calendar or not.

**Reference:**

[Graph API Get Calendar result in Resource not found by Shweta Choudhary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/471424/graph-api-get-calendar-result-in-resource-not-foun.html)

Comment: Thanks, @Rukmini I have added all 3 licences but still getting same error.

Comment: Also, I have configured a new mailbox in 

Microsoft 365 admin center -> Teams & groups -> Shared mailboxes -> Add a shared mailbox. I have also added the user as a member to this mailbox. This user has a calendar, and I have added a test event.

Comment: Could you include the Grant Type you are using to generate access token?

Comment: I am using authorization_code

Comment: Could you confirm whether you have added the licenses to the user you want to retrieve details for?